# html - if prefix doesn't seem to work

Tags: html

I'd like to detect if the user uses IE or another browser. So just after

```
<!doctype html>
```

but before

```
<html lang="pl-PL">
```

I put this code:

```
  <![if !IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <![endif]>

  <!--[if IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style-ie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe conditional comments have been deprecated in html5.

Answer (score 0):

The `<link>` tag should be a child of the `<head>` tag.

```
<html lang="pl-PL">
  <head>
<![if !IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<![endif]>
```

Comment: OK, I don't see any difference, but... If I'm right this should work like this: if user uses some other browser than IE than it should link to style.css. If user uses IE it should view website without CSS styling, because there's no css file that the code links to, right?

Comment: In your example the link tag was outside the html tag.

Comment: Yes, okay, I get it. I put the code inside the head tag, but I see no difference. I thought there should be some.